# XOM.nu settings close tags format

Tags: java, xml, xom

How can I set uп Xom.nu in such a way that elements are closed like so:

`<Node></Nodes>` and not `<Node/>`.

The reason why I want to do it in this way is that this XML is going to be imported into a tool which, unfortunately recognizes the former "close tag convention".

Comment: XOM has no way to do that. Do you need to use XOM?

Comment: Well it is not compulsory to use it, but in comparison with other java XML apis I find it the most user-friendly and intuitive

Comment: @skaffman I'm open or any other suggestions for XML apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOM is a pretty bare-bones API, it doesn't provide this level of fine control. The [JDOM API](http://www.jdom.org/), on the other hand, does do this, via its `Format` class, which [allows you to tightly control output formatting](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/Format.html#setExpandEmptyElements%28boolean%29), including non-collapsing of empty elements.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I even managed to port my XOM code without much changing :D